# Build failure during install sqlite3 on Mac OS X 10.6 using MacPorts 1.8

Tags: build, macos, sqlite, macports

When I do this command :

```
sudo port clean sqlite3
sudo port install sqlite3
```

I get this error :

```
--->  Computing dependencies for sqlite3
--->  Fetching sqlite3
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for sqlite3
--->  Extracting sqlite3
--->  Configuring sqlite3
--->  Building sqlite3
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.6.18" && /usr/bin/gnumake all " returned error 2
Command output: libtool: compile:  /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.6.18 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -arch x86_64 -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -I. -I./src -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1 -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o >/dev/null 2>&1
./libtool --mode=link /usr/bin/gcc-4.2  -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.6.18 -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -arch x86_64 -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -I. -I./src -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG   -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1   -L/opt/local/lib  -o libsqlite3.la sqlite3.lo  \
   -rpath "/opt/local/lib" -version-info "8:6:8"
libtool: link: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libsqlite3.0.dylib  .libs/sqlite3.o   -L/opt/local/lib  -arch x86_64   -install_name  /opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib -compatibility_version 9 -current_version 9.6 -Wl,-single_module
libtool: link: dsymutil .libs/libsqlite3.0.dylib || :
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsqlite3.dylib" && ln -s "libsqlite3.0.dylib" "libsqlite3.dylib")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libsqlite3.a  sqlite3.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libsqlite3.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsqlite3.la" && ln -s "../libsqlite3.la" "libsqlite3.la" )
./libtool --mode=link /usr/bin/gcc-4.2  -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.6.18 -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -arch x86_64 -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -I. -I./src -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG   -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1   -L/opt/local/lib  -DHAVE_READLINE=1 -I/opt/local/include \
  -o sqlite3 ./src/shell.c libsqlite3.la \
  -L/opt/local/lib -lreadline -lm -lncurses  -rpath "/opt/local/lib"
libtool: link: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.6.18 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -arch x86_64 -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -I. -I./src -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DHAVE_READLINE=1 -I/opt/local/include -o .libs/sqlite3 ./src/shell.c  -L/opt/local/lib ./.libs/libsqlite3.dylib -lreadline -lm -lncurses
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libreadline.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libncurses.dylib, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols:
  "_readline", referenced from:
      _process_input in ccGpsFnz.o
  "_add_history", referenced from:
      _process_input in ccGpsFnz.o
  "_read_history", referenced from:
      _main in ccGpsFnz.o
  "_stifle_history", referenced from:
      _main in ccGpsFnz.o
  "_write_history", referenced from:
      _main in ccGpsFnz.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gnumake: *** [sqlite3] Error 1

Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

I have installed the developer tools Xcode 3.2 for Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and I have updated to the latest version of MacPorts and sync'ed my ports tree. I can install other things via MacPorts.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deactivating readline in macports and then reinstall sqlite3. This seemed to get it to install when I had this issue.

```
sudo port deactivate readline
sudo port install sqlite3
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with py25-gtk > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478263/build-failure-during-install-py25-gtk-on-mac-os-x-10-6-using-macports-1-8

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to reinstall all ports because I upgraded to a new OS version (10.5 -> 10.6).

For more details look the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478263/build-failure-during-install-py25-gtk-on-mac-os-x-10-6-using-macports-1-8/1479307#1479307)

Read the complete documentation to reinstall ports at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration