# Build failure during install py25-gtk on Mac OS X 10.6 using MacPorts 1.8

Tags: python, macos, gtk, macports, getopt

When I do this command :

```
sudo port clean py25-gtk
sudo port install py25-gtk
```

I get this error :

```
--->  Computing dependencies for py25-gtk
--->  Building getopt
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_getopt/work/getopt-1.1.4" && /usr/bin/make -j2 all LIBCGETOPT=0 prefix=/opt/local mandir=/opt/local/share/man CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 " returned error 2
Command output:       _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _print_help in getopt.o
      _parse_error in getopt.o
      _our_realloc in getopt.o
      _our_malloc in getopt.o
      _set_shell in getopt.o
      _set_shell in getopt.o
      _add_longopt in getopt.o
      _add_long_options in getopt.o
      _add_long_options in getopt.o
      _normalize in getopt.o
      _main in getopt.o
      _main in getopt.o
      _main in getopt.o
      _main in getopt.o
      _main in getopt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [getopt] Error 1

Error: The following dependencies failed to build: atk gtk-doc gnome-doc-utils rarian getopt intltool gnome-common p5-pathtools p5-scalar-list-utils gtk2 cairo libpixman pango shared-mime-info xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXrandr libglade2 py25-cairo py25-numpy fftw-3 py25-nose py25-gobject
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

For information getopt isn't installed with macports, it's in /usr/bin/getopt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to reinstall all ports because I upgraded to a new OS version (10.5 -> 10.6).

To reinstall your ports, save the list of your installed ports:

```
port installed > myports.txt
```

Clean any partially completed builds, and uninstall all installed ports:

```
sudo port clean installed
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

Browse myports.txt and install the ports that you actually want to use (as opposed to those that are only needed as dependencies) one by one, remembering to specify the appropriate variants:

```
sudo port install portname +variant1 +variant2 ...
```

To resolve my problem, i can do and :

```
sudo port install py25-gtk
```

Now it's work !

Read the complete documentation to reinstall ports at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration