# readline in C doesn't work

Tags: c

I've never encountered such a problem before. I was writing simple C program on Mac and compiled as usual with gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

#define MAXLINES 5

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];
void writel(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void quicksort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);
void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);

/* sort input lines */
int main() {
  int nlines; /* number of lines to read */
  int i = 0;

  /* saves lines in the array lineptr */
  while (i < MAXLINES) {
    lineptr[i] = readline("Enter a line: \n");
    i++;
  }

  quicksort(lineptr, 0, MAXLINES-1);
  writel(lineptr, MAXLINES);
  return 0;
}
```

It seems that readline was causing the trouble. Once I commented out `lineptr[i] = readline("Enter a line: \n");` it compiled okay. But I don't understand what is wrong with readline here... The error is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_readline", referenced from:
>       _main in cckHOwOt.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Thanks for anyone who can give some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: It's some sort of build configuration problem -- not really associated with readline per se, but with the I/O library being linked.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470560/build-failure-during-install-sqlite3-on-mac-os-x-10-6-using-macports-1-8

Comment: em, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compile your code with `-lreadline`. Of course you also need readline-devel package installed on your system.